# is my family owed money for the patents my father created while working for chase durus while he was alive

Tags: family, father, money

My father has patents that he created to help make the industrial doors that are in every grocery store. he is on Chase Doors website. he passed away about 10 years ago. He made Patents while working there. That company has been making probably millions of dollars over the years. the company is located in Redmond Oregon. I always wondered does that company owe my family money?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely nothing. People who are hired by companies to develop technology and products are paid by the company for those efforts in salary and other compensation.

Comment: ok thanks George

Comment: @Dhuskers43 In the startup world, one will not be hired unless an IP assignment agreement is signed typically along with a non-compete clause which means that within the same field one may not even patent stuff on their own free time. Sorry for your loss!

Answer (score 1):

George White's answer is almost certainly correct. I worked for 26 years at a company and was a named inventor on over 90 patents. At my company I was paid one dollar when an application was filed for signing the assignments and if a patent issued about $500 in company stock. Only one payout per patent family. Different companies may have different inducements to encourage innovation, but in general you get your salary and the company owns your work product.